# PHPSpreadsheet clear formatting

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Im using PHPSpreadsheet to read and get data from an excel file and put the data into my database.

I used cell iterator to iterate data between cells. And i found that some data are not readable. I try to open that file using Microsoft Excel and do 'clear formatting', and then the PHPSpreadsheet can read it.

So my question is, how can PHPSpreadsheet clear the formatting for that spreadsheet file? To make sure PHPSpreadsheet can easily read the value. Thank you.

Note : That unreadable data is not a chinesse or any foreign character, it just a simple "AUKEY" string

Answer (score 2):

You can set option setReadDataOnly on the reader, to instruct the
reader to ignore styling, data validation, … and just read cell data:
e.g.
    `$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();`
    `$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);`
    `$spreadsheet = $reader->load("05featuredemo.xls");`